# issue in Parsing Json object using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I have following JSON object.

```
{
    "newArrival": {
        "head": {
            "name": "New Arrivals",
            "url": "/new-arrivals/"
        },
        "banner": [
            {
                "name": "Lee Cooper",
                "url": "/Lee_Cooper/",
                "src": "http://indfas1.images.com/images/abc/menu/new-arrival-lee-cooper-1.jpg",
                "alt": "",
                "title": ""
            },
            {
                "name": "Ray Ban",
                "url": "/Ray-Ban/",
                "src": "http://indfas1.images.com/images/abc/menu/new-arrival-ray-ban-1.jpg",
                "alt": "",
                "title": ""
            },
            {
                "name": "Vero Moda",
                "url": "/vero-moda/",
                "src": "http://indfas1.images.com/images/abc/menu/new-arrival-vero-moda-1.jpg",
                "alt": "",
                "title": ""
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to read head and banner tags value. I'm using following Jquery code:

```
$.each(json.newArrival, function (i, newArr) {
    $.each(newArr, function (index, value) {
        alert(value);
    }); 
});
```

But, I'm not able to read head and banner in any way.

Anybody Please help!!

Thanks a lot in advance.

--
Ashu

Comment: use `json.newArrival[0]` instead of `json.newArrival`

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/VjLGA/

Comment: there is something wrong with your profile. this isn't a question a "Senior software engineer" should ask

Comment: @thenewseattle: It's not about profile. Sometimes things does not work as you expected and when you are in hurry and don't want to stuck in such stupid logics and want to finsh them asap to move forward in your work.

Comment: @AshuS you must select johan's answer as chosen answer if you think solved your question.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have "works" as is. However, there is a difference between how you will have to access head data and banner data.

Because head is an object, your inner each will iterate over its members, i.e. newArrival.head.name and newArrivale.head.url.

Because banner is an array, you will be iterating over objects. If you then each through those objects, you will be accessing name, url, src etc.

Thus, what you have should alert, in sequence New Arrivals, /new-arrivals/, [Object object], [Object object], [Object object]

Why not directly access the members of newArrival.head (if you need them) and then iterate over newArrival.banner with

```
alert(json.newArrival.head.name);
alert(json.newArrival.head.url);
$.each(json.newArrival.banner, function (i, newArr) {
    $.each(newArr, function (index, value) {
        alert(value);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

go to which ever node you want in place of json.newArrival.banner

```
$.each(json.newArrival.banner, function (i, newArr) {
    alert(newArr.name);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4X9cX/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
"newArrival": {
    "head": {
        "name": "New Arrivals",
        "url": "/new-arrivals/"
    },
    "banner": [
        {
            "name": "Lee Cooper",
            "url": "/Lee_Cooper/",
            "src": "http://indfas1.images.com/images/abc/menu/new-arrival-lee-cooper-1.jpg",
            "alt": "",
            "title": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "Ray Ban",
            "url": "/Ray-Ban/",
            "src": "http://indfas1.images.com/images/abc/menu/new-arrival-ray-ban-1.jpg",
            "alt": "",
            "title": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "Vero Moda",
            "url": "/vero-moda/",
            "src": "http://indfas1.images.com/images/abc/menu/new-arrival-vero-moda-1.jpg",
            "alt": "",
            "title": ""
        }
    ]
}
})


 var data1 = JSON.parse(data) 

 console.log(data1.newArrival.head.name)
 console.log(data1.newArrival.head.url)

 console.log(data1.newArrival.banner[0].name)
 console.log(data1.newArrival.banner[0].url)
 console.log(data1.newArrival.banner[0].src)
 console.log(data1.newArrival.banner[0].src)
```

This will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try This ..

```
var JsonObj = Say yourValues
var headObj = JsonObj.newArrival.head; //head json values 
var bannerObj = JsonObj.newArrival.banner; //banner json Values
```

Say you want to access **bannerObj**  first name...

```
 alert(bannerObj [0].name);
```